# malloc(): corrupted top size on fwrite

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I have suddenly begun getting a very odd abort on an `fwrite`:

the problem is, if I put the same `fwrite` in the `main` function, it works, if I put it in an `fwrite` deeper in the application, I get the `malloc` error. The read write is more complicated but I tried this simple `fwrite` and had the same exact problem.

```
  FILE *genFp2;

  if ((genFp2 = fopen("csr1.der", "wb")) == NULL) 
  {
    INFO("failed to create DER encoded CSR file");
    return NULL;
  }
  assert((genFp2 != NULL) && "Cannot open file");
  fwrite("The One and Only", sizeof(char), 16, genFp2);
  fflush(genFp2);
  fclose(genFp2);
```

Error: **`malloc(): corrupted top size`**

any thoughts, am lost in the weeks.

thank you.

Update: it is a seg11 inside `fwrite`: at least that is what it looks like.

```
==9379== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9379==    at 0x4903ED4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.4 (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so)
==9379==
==9379== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==9379==    at 0x495F944: write (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so)
==9379==  Address 0x49e8028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==9379==    at 0x48463D0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:262)
==9379==    by 0x48F5B13: _IO_file_doallocate (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so)
==9379==
--9379-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--9379-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x5DE3494A;  sp: 0x62548e58

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
==9379==    at 0x3805CC9C: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:285)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==9379==    at 0x48463D0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:262)
==9379==    by 0x48F67AF: __fopen_internal (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so)
```

Comment: This looks fine.  There's probably some issue elsewhere in your code.  Try running it through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: If you can't use `valgrind` for some reason, compiling with the address sanitizer enabled would help.

Comment: Note that `fclose` will also flush the file, so no need for that `fflush` call. Also note that `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be `1` (it's part of the C specification).

Comment: i am looking at valgrind now, thank you - this is an odd one, this ran for almost 30 days and then this started. not sure what i changed to create the problem but you suggestion may take me in the right direction

Comment: Do you use a version control system (like e.g. Git)? Then rollback commit by commit until it starts working. The last commit you rollbacked probably contains the error. And if you don't use a VCS then take this as a lesson to always use it, even for personal and possible simple projects.

Comment: unfortunately no version control - and i do know better -

i am getting a seg11 in the fread (thanks to valgrind:

Comment: Learn how to use [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Can't reproduce.  [A program containing only the code you've provided](https://godbolt.org/z/9PYx3crEn) runs correctly with no valgrind errors.  Therefore the problem is likely to be in some other part of your code.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There is a good chance you are reading past the end of an array allocated from the heap. The allocation size is most probably too small. Look into this.

Comment: Thank you everyone, especially for the valgrind recommendation - it led me in the right direction ---

Found it through brute force - calling the fwrite until i narrowed it down :

Solution - in a very unrelated part of the application i overwrote a buffer by one type - and it was the cascade effect. 

Again, thank you for the guidance.